# Equivalent for MFMailComposer on Mac

Tags: macos, cocoa

iOS has nice `MFMailComposer` class that let's the user compose an email.   What is the best way to open up a new window in Mac Mail with the email pre-formatted as is done by share buttons for Safari in Mountain Lion and Reeder app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I think the recently introduced 10.8 `NSSharingService` should be my answer: http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSharingService_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Is there a way to pre-fill the destination e-mail addresses?

Comment: Starting with OS X 10.9, you can set the `recipients` property for a sharing service:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSharingService_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSSharingService/recipients