# Sending mails from app in OSX

Tags: objective-c, email

What's the best way to send an e-mail from my OSX app.
I'm developing a app and i need to send an invoice by mail to my customers.

I've been looking on the internet for information but most of the info is for IOS.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747894/equivalent-for-mfmailcomposer-on-mac). for help. mac osx already have a sharing feature , that will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the information.
Tomorrow i'm going to look at the link and information.

When something is still not clear i will be back.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a server to send your e-mail ? Not only server but one server-side application to due that.. did you can you a java application with SES (AWS Amazon) integration or google app engine solution for example.

Comment: why you need some third party service , when its already available in mac osx.

Comment: without third party service.. can you send your message without Mail application or other client mail ?

Comment: question is about sending mail from osx app, not from back end or from other third party service.

Comment: I want to send the email from my app.
It's not my idea to do it by a third party.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different ways to do this, from connecting to a server yourself and sending the appropriate headers and encoded body to the very easiest which is just opening a mail url, which will invoke the default behavior...

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"mailto://bob@example.com?subject=test"]];
```